# Dataframe: Permutations after grouping column data into a dictionary/list with recurring elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm struggling with manipulating large sets of data into condensed rows that will allow me to run permutations on and get all possible combinations.
Basically this is the structure:

```
    PLOT    SEED    SUB EDGE    PT  0   1   2   3
1   117 1   1   1   2   8   None    None    None
2   117 1   1   1   3   8   None    None    None
3   117 1   1   2   1   8   None    None    None
4   117 1   1   2   2   6   7   8   None
5   117 1   2   1   1   8   None    None    None
```

I'm not sure if I should use lists or dictionaries, as this data should have thousands to even millions of rows in the future.

The idea is to add the `['SUB','EDGE','PT']` values to each value in the `[0:]` columns (it won't necessarily end at 3), so that for example row number 4 will look like:

```
    PLOT    SEED    SUB TYPES
4   117 1   1   [1,2,2,6],[1,2,2,7],[1,2,2,8]
```

OR dictionaries:

```
    PLOT    SEED    SUB TYPES
4   117 1   1   {'SUB':1, 'EDGE':2, 'PT':2, 'TYPE':6},{'SUB':1, 'EDGE':2, 'PT':2, 'TYPE':7},{'SUB':1, 'EDGE':2, 'PT':2, 'TYPE':8}
```

And then run permutations on each `['PLOT','SEED']` using the ['SUB'] column.
That means that `if Plot 117, Seed 1` has `2 Subs`, it will run all possible combinations between all the options in Sub1 and all the options in Sub1, while keeping the `['PLOT','SEED']` data. So in this case (building on the original 5 row table up top):

```
# 1st Sub:
[1,1,2,8],[1,1,3,8],[1,2,1,8],[1,2,2,6],[1,2,2,7],[1,2,2,8]
# 2nd Sub:
[2,1,1,8]
```

And What I should get is:

```
#Plot 117 Seed 1 Permutations:
[[1,1,2,8],[2,1,1,8]], [[1,1,3,8],[2,1,1,8]], [[1,2,1,8],[2,1,1,8]], ...
Or with Dictionaries:
[{'SUB':1, 'EDGE':2, 'PT':2, 'TYPE':6},{'SUB':2, 'EDGE':1, 'PT':1, 'TYPE':8}], ...
```

Obviously this needs to iterate over the entire dataset for each `['PLOT','SEED']`, of which there will be many, and also in many cases there will be more than 2 'SUB' per PLOT+SEED.

I tried many things like 'groupby', for example:

```
df_grouped_edge = df_joined.groupby(['PLOT','SEED','SUB','EDGE'], as_index=False).agg(np.array)
df_grouped_edge
```

For which I get:

```
    PLOT    SEED    SUB EDGE    PT  0   1   2   3
0   117 1   1   1   [2, 3]  [8, 8]  [None, None]    [None, None]    [None, None]
1   117 1   1   2   [1, 2, 3]   [8, 6, 8]   [None, 7, None] [None, 8, None] [None, None, None]
```

This is not what I'm looking for, or at least I don't think it is and I don't know how to work with that output. Tried many other grouping attempts the last two days but I can't seem to get it work, and I understand that looping over large datasets per item/column is a very wrong way of working (and I should vectorize it, I just don't understand how yet).

I hope I explained myself well, I know this is a big question but I'm really at a loss.
Starting to learn SQL very soon but I'm not there yet, and I have to get this done.

Thank you very much!
Lev

Comment: Is there a reason you can't keep the data as rows? Trying to encode it as nested dicts/lists like that seems like a "backward step".

Comment: I need to find all the permutations within certain parameters, meaning I need to slice the dataframe and group it, and then to do the permutations with a list (and for that reason I want to create a list of dictionaries)

Comment: From where are you getting the values of EDGE, PT ..., it seems that they have the same values in the discitonaries of Row4

Comment: In row 4 there are 3 integers in columns [0:3], because of that the EDGE, PT data is repeated. I'm already at the stage of having these lists of dictionaries ready, now moving to permutations. Will try to update an answer when I'm done but I'll still be happy to hear if anyone has an advice as to how to do it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it using .melt():

```
df.melt(id_vars=["PLOT", "SEED", "SUB", "EDGE", "PT"], 
        var_name="DROP", 
        value_name="TYPO",
        ignore_index=True) #False here leaves duplicates of the original indexes
df=df.drop('DROP', axis=1)
# Drop Scenarios with no typos matching
df=df.dropna()
```

After getting each typo value as a row, I used `.groupby(['PLOT', 'SEED']` into dictionaries, then iterated over each entry in the dict and used `groupby('SUB'...` everything in place.

Then in each dict in a large list I only used the key that has the list of lists (with all the options) and I used `itertools.product` to get all the combinations between said lists.

Obviously this required a lot of work on the data structures, adding back the corresponding data into each dict, probably not the cleanest work, but it did the job.

My problem now is that .product stopped working due to MemoryError when the dataset became too big:
[Using np.meshgrid on list of lists with different lengths in a large dataset (instead of itertools.product)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559405/using-np-meshgrid-on-list-of-lists-with-different-lengths-in-a-large-dataset-in)

Answer (score 1):

First, group your data by the columns `['PLOT', 'SEED']`. This will allow you to iterate over each unique combination of `['PLOT', 'SEED']` in your dataset.

```py
grouped_data = df.groupby(['PLOT', 'SEED'])
```

Define a function that takes a group and performs the necessary operations to generate the combinations. This function will be applied to each group using `apply()`.

```py
import itertools

def generate_combinations(group):
    sub_values = group['SUB'].unique()
    combinations = list(itertools.product(*sub_values))
    
    # Create a new DataFrame to store the combinations
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    
    for combination in combinations:
        # Create a new row with the combination values
        new_row = group.iloc[0].copy()
        new_row[['SUB', 'EDGE', 'PT']] = combination
        
        # Append the row to the result DataFrame
        result_df = result_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    
    return result_df
```

Apply the `generate_combinations` function to each group in the grouped data and concatenate the results.

```py
result = pd.concat([generate_combinations(group) for _, group in grouped_data], ignore_index=True)
```

Now, the result should contain the DataFrame with all the possible combinations for each unique `['PLOT', 'SEED']` combination, based on the values in the `'SUB'` column.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm getting this error: ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value. I'm guessing it's trying to create a very different amount of columns than the original [0,1,2,3] columns, but I don't fully understand how it works...

Comment: This may be due to null values in certain rows. Try after `dropna()`