# Using np.meshgrid on list of lists with different lengths in a large dataset (instead of itertools.product)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-itertools

I'm trying to get all the combinations of lists of varying sizes that are being generated in a very large dataset. Using itertools.product worked until the dataset became very big, then it started producing a `MemoryError`. I understand that `np.meshgrid` works significantly faster, but I have a problem getting it to work.

**The basic issue:**
When trying to create a very basic np.meshgrid test:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8]
d = [9,10,11,12]

listoflists=[a,b,c,d]
maxlen = max([len(x) for x in listoflists])
listoflists = np.asarray(listoflists, dtype=object)

np.array(np.meshgrid(listoflists)).T.reshape(-1,maxlen)
```

I get this:

```
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6]), list([7, 8]),
        list([9, 10, 11, 12])]], dtype=object)
```

But when I manually input the lists `np.array(np.meshgrid(a,b,c,d)).T.reshape(-1,maxlen)` I get the proper result:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  7,  9],
       [ 1,  5,  7,  9],
       ...
       [ 3,  6,  8, 12]])
```

Not to mention that I need the reshape to be different for each iteration because the max number of elements in the lists `(x)` is different `T.reshape(-1,x)`, I also can't seem to get `np.meshgrid` to work on an existing list of lists (which exists in each iteration in my dataset).

**More in depth:**
I have dictionaries containing lists of dictionaries, to simplify the data structure looks like this:

```
example = 
[{'A': '0',
  'B': '1',
  'C': [[{'ITEM1': '1', 'ITEM2': '1'},
    {'ITEM1': '1', 'ITEM2': '2'},
    {'ITEM1': '1', 'ITEM2': '3'},
    {'ITEM1': '1', 'ITEM2': '4'}],
   [{'ITEM1': '2', 'ITEM2': '1'},
    {'ITEM1': '2', 'ITEM2': '2'},
    {'ITEM1': '2', 'ITEM2': '3'}],
   [{'ITEM1': '3', 'ITEM2': '1'},
    {'ITEM1': '3', 'ITEM2': '2'}],
   [{'ITEM1': '4', 'ITEM2': '1'},
    {'ITEM1': '4', 'ITEM2': '2'},
    {'ITEM1': '4', 'ITEM2': '3'},
    {'ITEM1': '4', 'ITEM2': '4'},
    {'ITEM1': '4', 'ITEM2': '5'}]]},
 {'A': '0',
  'B': '2',
  'C': [[{'ITEM1': '1', 'ITEM2': '1'},
    {'ITEM1': '1', 'ITEM2': '2'}, ... ]
```

So I'm iterating on this list of dictionaries, in each iteration I'm using only `'C'` to get all the combinations within that key, then I add a `'D: [combinations of C]'` and get rid of the C key, so I'm left with `{'A: '0', 'B': '1', D: [combinations of C]}`.

I was using itertools.product in a loop looking like this:

```
for a in example:
    b = list(itertools.product(*a['C']))
    a['D']=b
    del a['C']
```

This worked very well while the dataset was relatively small, but as the dataset grew bigger this started creating a `MemoryError`.
From what I've read - meshgrid works significantly faster. The problem is that the solutions regarding `np.meshgrid` that I keep seeing all work with a pre-defined length of lists (for the `reshape(-1,x)`) and the input of lists is manual.My dataset can be anything (the `'C'` column can contain any number of lists within the list, with each nested list having different lengths).

Thanks a bunch!
Lev

Comment: The `MemoryError` indicates that the issue is that the number of combinations is large (which makes sense for a large dataset), so it cannot fit in memory. Using `np.meshgrid` will not solve that problem. Do you need to store all the combinations? If not, an alternative method would be to write a generator function (i.e. use `yield`) to create each combination on command, which does not require storage of the entire result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I do need each combination, as we're comparing between them and we need their data. This happens within each iteration of a bigger list of dictionaries. I will definitely look into yield to see if that can solve my problem

Comment: `meshgrid(a,b,c,d)` is different from `meshgrid([a,b,c,d])`

Comment: @LevZhitnik you need to unpack the `listoflists` with a `*` in the `meshgrid` to get the same result, so  `np.meshgrid(*listoflists)` should work.  and I'm unsure to understand the part about the lenght, but if I follow what you want to achieve, you should better use the len of the listoflists and not the maximum length of one of the lists, so more like `.reshape(-1,len(listoflists))`?